# The name and number of parameters

Tags: c, performance, optimization, memory-efficient

Up to this moment I know that it's quite important that the paramaters which are included in your code to have suggestive names, so that the code could be easy to read by anyone who has to read it. But ... in matters of memory, run time, how important is that the used parameters to not be too many or to have too long names? Could this be something to be aware of or is it not so important for the efficiency of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the parameters/arguments matters **absolutely zero** at runtime. The compiler does not use the names when generating object code. They will not appear in your binary unless you take special effort to get them there. They are only for the human who reads the code. As such, they should be as long and descriptive as necessary, but no longer.

On the other hand, having *too many* parameters can indeed have a minor effect on the runtime speed of your code, since each time that function is called, all those parameters have to be pushed. But that is really not the most significant issue. A bigger problem is *usability*—a function becomes very hard to understand and use [correctly] if it takes a bazillion parameters. Design your functions so that they are easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly. (It is also worth pointing out that a function that takes a lot of parameters is *probably* violating the single responsibility principle.)